# Mongodb document failed validation with 121 code

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My schema is very simple but still failing.

```
db.createCollection("person", { validator : { 
 
      jsonSchema : { bsonType: "object", 
   properties : { 
            firstName : { 
             bsonType : "string", 
             description: "firstName is required and its string"} } }

  } });
```

My insertScript:

```
        db.person.insert({"firstName" : "Jhon"});
```

And its failed with `121` code saying `Document failed validation`,

**EDIT**

```
db.person.validate({"firstName" : "Jhon"});
```

above statement returns success.

Please help me on this.

Comment: I think the syntax should be: `$jsonSchema ` (with the `$` prefix).

Comment: @prasad_ thank you, I have tried `$` also still same

Comment: I think you are missing target field definition like ``required: [ "firstName" ]`` beneath ``properties``